# Projectile: where is the project name stored / set?

Tags: projectile, smart-mode-line

I'm using [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile), and after seeing the really [awesome .emacs file](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org#projectile) I decided to copy the lines that set the mode-line to display the project name, like so:

```
:config
  (projectile-global-mode 1)
  (setq-default ;; <snip>
   projectile-mode-line '(:eval (projectile-project-name))))
```

I've got this included in my init.el and it *almost* works - the only problem is that the variable `projectile-project-name` is `nil`, so it doesn't actually show the name of the project (and this is even after I've done `C-C p p` and chosen a project.

How is `projectile-project-name` set and/or where is that information stored? (Maybe in the `.projectile` file?)

Comment: As per your code, you're calling the `projectile-project-name` *function* which does not purely depend on the variable of the same name (but does use that value by preference, when it's non-nil).

Comment: It seems that projectile *already* sets `projectile-mode-line` to a value which includes the project name.  Or at least the current version does.  If you weren't already seeing that, your problem is probably that you have a custom mode line which isn't displaying `projectile-mode-line` at all.

Comment: `(:eval (format " Projectile[%s]" (projectile-project-name)))` is the value I'm seeing for `projectile-mode-line`

Comment: I'm using `smart-mode-line`, which seems to embed the `projectile-mode-line` into the mode line at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `projectile-project-name` being a function - I hadn't caught that. When I call it interactively (using `M-:`) it returns `'-'`.....  because that particular file wasn't part of a project.  It returns something reasonable when the file (buffer) that's open is part of the project

Answer (score 1):

Much thanks to @phils for helping me to realize that Projectile displays the project name when the buffer that has the focus is in a project.  If that buffer's file isn't in a project then it displays `'-'`

Thinking about this, this makes perfect sense - the error is clearly on my end :)

I think I was confused because Visual Studio / Eclipse / etc do it the opposite way - once you've got a project open you're always 'in' that project, even if you open unrelated files.

Both ways seems reasonable, and now I know how Projectile works :)